# orderby parameter in woocommerce for category

Tags: rest, woocommerce

I am trying to sort categories of woocommerce by orderby. Based on the refrence there is orderby parameter for this. here is the link:
http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-product-categories
how can i use this parameter?

Comment: just add `orderby=>name` to your other request param, category will be order  by it's name.

Comment: @RaunakGupta Thank you very much, Would you give me an example: My code is :  var Woocommerce= WC.WC();
  Woocommerce.get('products/categories?filter[orderby]=slug',function(err,data, res){  ..... But i get no result. It is not ordered by slug at all.

Comment: try this way. `$data = [
 'orderby' => 'slug',
 'order' => 'desc'
];

print_r($woocommerce->get('products/categories', $data));`